# How to use fringe indicators to display register positions?

Tags: fringe, registers, fringe-mode

I know that i can use customize `register-marker-face` to make position-registers location visible, - is there is a way to mark resisters position using left fringe?

Also, I am using "Mitsuharu Yamamoto's Mac port " on Mac , see emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc3

Comment: I would recommend having a look at the `fringe-helper` library https://github.com/nschum/fringe-helper.el that contains a README.md file that states in relevant part:  "*`fringe-helper-insert` inserts a fringe bitmap at point*".  You, or a motivated forum participant, will likely need to create a custom solution that meets your needs.

Comment: Standard Emacs doesn't have a `register-marker-face` AFAIK, so you might be using another register package.  Could you clarify, since the answer will probably depend on that?

Comment: I am using "Mitsuharu Yamamoto's Mac port " on Mac , see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc3

Comment: Thank you for info @lawlist - i will check that library!

Comment: @Yatima: Please edit your answer to include the extra data: your comment may not always be displayed.

Comment: @Stefan - thanks, i updated question and added it include Emacs package info

Comment: I still see no trace of `register-marker-face` in a git checkout of `emacs-mac`.

Comment: @Stefan oh, - you are right, - looks like `register-marker-face` was introduced by some of the locally installed packages